# How to disable the auto layout of the IntelliJ IDEA UML Diagram?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA and I like the its responsiveness.

In Eclipse I use ObjectAid to assist in designing my application structure. IntelliJ IDEA does have a UML diagram but it got really annoying when it keeps re-adjusting my diagram layout to what it thinks is a neat structure. Everytime I add/remove a class, it will re-adjust the layout. It may look neat, but it makes little sense to me. I like to manually place my class model in the exact place I leave it. Why oh why does IntelliJ think it knows best? Can I change this behavior? I can't find any settings in the settings menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this behaviour in the preferences under "Tools" -> "Diagrams". There is an option "Do relayout when new elements were added" which you need to disable.

Note: IntelliJ 2016.3

[image: Where to disable the automatic relayout of diagrams in IntelliJ]

Comment: Still gets frustrating when you do things.  I wish there was just a custom layout!

Comment: This option doesn't work for me, at least not with IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1. Does anyone know how to fix this annoying behavior?